# Node mySQL Express to Json

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, handlebars.js

I have this mySQL query with an INNER JOIN, which I want to use with Handlebars, although it's a single return, it still returns muliple results, because the image table contains more results.

How can I return a single result, and then have the images in a seperate json string?

Here is the query:

```js
app.get("/car/:brand-:model-:id", function (req, res) {
    let userName;
    if (req.user != undefined) {
        userName = req.user.displayName;
    }
    const carSql = `SELECT * FROM cars INNER JOIN carimage ON cars.id = carimage.carId WHERE carimage.carId = ${req.params.id}`;
    const carQuery = db.query(carSql, (err, results) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const data = {
            car: results,
            username: userName
        }
        //res.render("pages/car", data);
        res.send(data);
    });
});
```

Which then returns this JSON:

```js
{
  car: [
  {
    id: 274,
    userId: 10157597945502792,
    brand: "Ford",
    carId: 246,
    image: "carimages-1569568518629.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 275,
    userId: 10157597945502792,
    brand: "Ford",
    carId: 246,
    image: "carimages-1569568518649.jpg"
  }
  ]
}
```

What I want, is to merge the results into one result, and then have the images as nested JSON.

Is this possible?

Comment: add a `GROUP BY cars.carId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with 2 queries: one for the car, the other for its images. Something like:

```
app.get("/car/:brand-:model-:id", function (req, res) {
    let userName;
    if (req.user != undefined) {
        userName = req.user.displayName;
    }
    const carSql = `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car.id = ${req.params.id}`;
    const carQuery = db.query(carSql, (err, car) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        const imagesSql = `SELECT * FROM carimage WHERE carimage.carId = ${req.params.id}`;
        const imageQuery = db.query(carSql, (err, results) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            const data = {
               car: car[0],
               images: results,
               username: userName
            }
          res.send(data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Man you nailed this one! Just what I was out for, thanks :)